# Recording slide transition times in a Powerpoint presentation

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I'm wanting to reliably record the times at which a lecturer changes (advances or reverses) slides in a live Powerpoint presentation. This is to enable jpeg images of that presentation to be synced against a separate video camera recording of the lecture. Ideally I would like to capture into an external text file the time and slide number

Impactica have a "Time Recorder" add-in that does this, but it doesn't capture if the lecturer returns to an earlier slide. Also it writes the results into an external text-file that is overwritten if the process is started again - I'm looking for something more fool-proof!

Any suggestions of existing add-ins would be appreciated, or should I be dusting off Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1):

Since nobody else has answered, I'll mention that I'm working on an add-in that does pretty much what you're after, one that'll be sold commercially.

I'd have to check to see whether it overwrites the text file it creates each time it's run; IIRC it does, by design/user spec, but it would be simple enough (and sensible) to allow the option to append the date/time to the end of the file name each time.

If you want to get in touch about it, you can use the contact link on the left of any page of my PPT addins site, [www.PPTools.com](http://www.PPTools.com)

If you're a coder, you could roll your own add-in (from within PowerPoint ... no need for Visual Studio).  I have another site, a PPT FAQ at [www.pptfaq.com](http://www.pptfaq.com)  where there are entries on creating add-ins.  You'd also want to look up the entry on making PPT respond to events; that's the key to recording slide timings.

Comment: could you update this post? I don't see a product that records transition times.

Answer (score 0):

I got something really basic working to record slide transitions.
It just appends a line of text to a log file during each transition event, nothing special.

See https://github.com/jason-s/pptimer